# headline: section without number and "Kapitel" with number

Tags: header-footer

Hello I would like to place at the left side of the headline only "Kapitel X" with X = number of this section ("Kapitel 3" or something else). On the right side I would like to place only the section name without the mark. Now i have reached that the second one works...

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\geometry{left=3.5cm,right=3.5cm,top=3cm,bottom=3cm}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}        
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}     
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}     
\usepackage{lmodern}            

%% Kopf- und Fußzeile
\usepackage[headsepline,footsepline,automark]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\renewcommand*{\sectionmarkformat}{%
}
\clearscrheadfoot                           
\ohead[]{\headmark}     
\ihead[]{Kapitel \sectionmark}
\setkomafont{pageheadfoot}{\sffamily}

\begin{document}

    
    \section{Hauptteil}
    

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\geometry{left=3.5cm,right=3.5cm,top=3cm,bottom=3cm}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}

%% Kopf- und Fußzeile
\usepackage[headsepline,footsepline,automark]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\renewcommand*{\sectionmarkformat}{Kapitel~\thesection\hfill}
\clearscrheadfoot
\ihead[]{\headmark}
\setkomafont{pageheadfoot}{\sffamily}

\begin{document}

\section{Hauptteil}

\end{document}
```